# New proposed H1B bill - who exactly does it affect?

Tags: united-states, immigration

The new proposed bill by the house can be found [here](https://lofgren.house.gov/uploadedfiles/high_skilled_bill_sxs_and_analysis_-1-2017__final.pdf) (the actual bill introduced, HR 670, is [here](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/115/hr670/text)):

Numerous sources from media claims that if this bill passes, your minimum wage would have to be $130,000 or higher to be eligible for H1B visa.

But looking at the actual bill brings some room for clarification, especially this section.

> SECTION. 3. STRENGTHENING INTEGRITY IN THE H-1B PROGRAM BY REFORMING THE
>   EXEMPT H-1B DEFINITION
>
> - Re-sets the current dependent wage exemption level of $60,000 which was established in 1998 and has since remained unchanged.
> - The new H-1B dependent employer wage exemption level will be set at 35 percentile points above the median for the most recent national annual wage for Computer and Mathematical Occupations (Group 15-0000) as published in the Department of Labor (DOL) Occupational Employment Statistics (OES).
> - Per the Department of Labor May 2015 Occupational Employment and Wages (the most recent data available), the new annual wage exemption level would be greater than $130,000
>     (http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes150000.htm).
> - Dependent employers are those with more than 15% of their workforce in H-1B status.
> - Unless dependent employers compensate their H-1B workers above the required wage level, they must make
>     attestations regarding recruitment and non-displacement of U.S. workers. Non-discretionary bonuses and similar compensation may be applied to wages based on their fair market value at the time of filing. No discretionary compensation may be counted towards wages.
> - Eliminates the Master’s Degree exemption for dependent employers.

I'm not a law expert, but the bill seems to indicate that these new changes would apply for **H1B dependent employers only**. In other words, I'm thinking this bill only applies to [companies where a considerable number of employees are under H1B visa](https://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/FactSheet62/whdfs62C.pdf).

Am I correct to think that this new bill applies to employees being hired by H1B dependent companies only or would this new annual wage exemption level of $130,000 actually apply to all prospective H1B applicants?

Comment: Just to clarify your block quote is an explanation of what HR 670 does. It may be that it is an accurate description i which case at least that section doesn't have the effect that was apparently claimed. But, it is not the bill itself.